# why accepted answer is shown down in this post?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

In this post, the accepted answer is shown on the 2nd place where the unaccepted is shown at first! Why?

Question: [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you currently have the answers sorted by "active". And self-accepts aren't pinned to the top.

When sorted by "votes" (the default), that accepted answer is on the top anyways since it has the most votes.